# Year show two times in text box when using date picker and date is not saving in db

Tags: datepicker

I am using jQuery datepicker.
When I choose the date from calender.The date show in text box like this 20132013-08-12 so please help me for saving the data in database.Data field type is date.
Datepicker format is mm/dd/yyyy

i have errors when inserting to my database it insert only 0000-00-00

my codes is

```
<code>    
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" />
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd" });
});
</script>
</code>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`yy` is the datepicker format for a 4-digit year, so try `dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"`

About saving the value to your database you would need to show us the code you have right now.